# SlimScroll creating issue in scrolling dropdowns in a form

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui, slimscroll

I have used *slimScroll* in my form and form contains multiple dropdown fields. When I load the page first time the dropdown fields item scrolls perfectly but on activating the main form scroll that is slimScroll I can't scroll inner dropdown fields. Please suggest solution to this.
I have used semantic ui dropdowns.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).